# Setting focus to an IE PDF style webpage for scraping using Excel VBA

Tags: html, css, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I navigate through this password protected website and get to a point where it opens up what looks like a child window but has a URL like `"http://yadayadayada**.pdf**?V42"`.

Although it's a PDF I can manually click on it to select and copy the data.

My problem is setting focus to it via code.

I've tried a number of variations of looping through the URLs of the open pages but it won't identify and I can't set focus to this one.

If all else fails, I can save it as a PDF, open it up via Adobe and scrape it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am not sure if I have realy understand what you want. The following code tests every open application wether it is the Internet Explorer and if yes, if it has the right url as location. More infos in the comments.

**Important:** It is not necessary to activate a tab to scrape data from it. I also do not know how to bring a tab to the foreground in IE. Somehow nobody knows ;-)

```
Sub ScrapeFromTabs()

Dim allShell As Object
Dim oneWindow As Object

  Set allShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  
  'Go through all open windows
  'Each tab in IE is treated as a window by the OS.
  For Each oneWindow In allShell.Windows
    'Check if it is a window of the Internet Explorer
    If InStr(1, UCase(oneWindow.FullName), "IEXPLORE") > 0 Then
      'Check whether the relevant parts are present in the URL
      If InStr(1, oneWindow.locationURL, "yadayadayada") > 0 And InStr(1, oneWindow.locationURL, ".pdf") > 0 Then
        'Do here what you want with the pdf
        'Whatever is possible with a pdf ... somthing like this
        'set nodeHeadline = oneWindow.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0)
        
        'It was the right tab with the pdf
        'Leave the loop
        Exit For
      End If
    End If
  Next oneWindow
End Sub
```

Comment: Well the code you provided still wasn't able to do what I wanted with the page which was just copy/paste it. The copy/paste always defaults to the original tab and not the newly opened one. What it did do though was identify the URL of the page I needed so I'm able to save/reopen/copy/paste and get what I need. There's common code string posted (Dim objShell, IE_count, x, my_url, childPage) which I had tried but wouldn't give me the URL. Yours does. Very strange the way this works because I can manually click the page and do the copy/paste. Anyway, I can certainly use this so, Thank you.

Comment: Looked over your answer again, Zwenn and yes, I shouldn't have to activate the page to scrape data from it. From my original tab I open a 2nd tab which is the pdf page and it looks like it is in focus but Ctrl-a or IE.execWB 17,0 selects everything from the original tab and not the one that just opened. Very strange